# While using OAuth 2, do I have to save the generated tokens into database?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

let's assume my WEB API hosted on IIS might stop and restarted under any circumstance. And I am using OAuth 2 and generated tokens successfully (with Expired date set).
I am just curious do I really have to save each token generated for the fact that my API could possibly restarted and lose its session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save a hashed version of the key to a database or possibly a user cookie.  As you stated if the application pool were to reset you would loose any session saved data.